# How to specify a bazel test env setting for a cc_test?

Tags: c, bazel, googletest

I'm trying to specify a env variable for a bazel test.  I've tried the following but it fails:

```
cc_test(
    name = "some_test",
    size = "small",
    deps = ["some_thing"],
    srcs = ["test.cc"],
    env = ["ENVVAR=foo"],
}
```

Comment: `env` is a dictionary. See here: https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#test.env

Answer (score 3):

I could not find this documented and I found it by trial and error.  This works.

```
cc_test(
    name = "some_test",
    size = "small",
    deps = ["some_thing"],
    srcs = ["test.cc"],
    env = {"ENVVAR:foo"},
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but I think it only works on the recent versions of Bazel